# IllegalArgumentException: column '_data' does not exist

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

In Nougat, this function is not working.

```
String path = getRealPathFromURI(this, getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM));
```

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) return contentUri.getPath();
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Crash log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{class path}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_data' does not exist
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_data' does not exist
   at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:333)
   at android.database.CursorWrapper.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CursorWrapper.java:87)
   at com.package.SaveImageActivity.getRealPathFromURI()
   at com.package.SaveImageActivity.onCreate()
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6672)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

This function is working properly in devices before Android N. I read the article [file:// scheme is now not allowed to be attached with Intent on targetSdkVersion 24 (Android Nougat)](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en). But couldn't find any solution. So please help.

Comment: Why are you trying to get a file path from the URI? Generally you should try to work with the URI as a stream because not all URIs are backed by a local file with a path. If your trying to get access to the file for the purpose of reading exif data then you could open it as a stream and use this support library to be able to read exif data. https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/introducing-the-exifinterface-support-library.html

Comment: @startoftext I know this is a late ask, but with your approach, there are various devices that show ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED for the image, and they can be either landscape or portrait, depending on the API version. For API 26 (Android 8) on an emulator, it gets rotated 90 degrees, whereas on API 29 and above (Android 9 and above) it shows a portrait image, without any rotation. Do you have any solution on that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> This function is working properly in devices before Android N

It works for very few `Uri` values, may not have a result (e.g., for things that are indexed by `MediaStore` that are not local files), and may not have a usable result (e.g., for files on removable storage).

> So please help.

Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`. Ideally, just use that stream directly, for whatever it is that you are trying to do. Or, use that `InputStream` and some `FileOutputStream` on a file that you control to make a copy of the content, then use that file.

Comment: What if I want file path & save file path in database?

Comment: What if I want file from Uri & display image?

Comment: @vidha:As I wrote in the answer, you need to make a **copy** of the data **to your own file** that you then manage.

Comment: I am facing the same issue but don't know to fix this, please help.
@Vidha could you provide your code here?

Comment: @BajrangHudda Please find the answer below.

Comment: Here's a good blog post that has an example similar to CommonsWare's suggested approach: https://medium.com/@sriramaripirala/android-10-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-da8b630a89df

Answer (score 51):

As per given answer by CommonsWare, the solution code is :

```
public static String getFilePathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    //copy file and send new file path 
    String fileName = getFileName(contentUri);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(fileName)) {
        File copyFile = new File(TEMP_DIR_PATH + File.separator + fileName);
        copy(context, contentUri, copyFile);
        return copyFile.getAbsolutePath();
    }
    return null;
}

public static String getFileName(Uri uri) {
    if (uri == null) return null;
    String fileName = null;
    String path = uri.getPath();
    int cut = path.lastIndexOf('/');
    if (cut != -1) {
        fileName = path.substring(cut + 1);
    }
    return fileName;
}

public static void copy(Context context, Uri srcUri, File dstFile) {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(srcUri);
        if (inputStream == null) return;
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(dstFile);
        IOUtils.copyStream(inputStream, outputStream);
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you.

The origin of IOUtils.copy is from this site : https://www.developerfeed.com/copy-bytes-inputstream-outputstream-android/ (May need to change a bit the exception but it works as needed)

Comment: works like a charm for all case in xiaomi Redmi 4A. Thanks a lot @vidha

Comment: what is TEMP_DIR_PATH  and IOUtils ? @vidha

Comment: @Redturbo    `apache.commons.io`

Comment: @vidha, IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream) contains error. can you update your answer with correct one ?

Comment: For  `TEMP_DIR_PAT` I used `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/YourAppName"`

Comment: Looks like this code have thrown a FileNotException:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47350375/3763032

Comment: @mochadwi, absolutely the code requires storage permission.

Comment: I've also implemented the manifest and runtime permission. This code works seamlessly, thanks @vidha

There's a problem with my code when creating a file that exists, I've deleted it directly instead of persisting it. Afterwards the `copy(in, out)` takes place, it can't find the source file, of course.

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my time, it works perfectly ! ;)

Comment: I used this line  'val newFile = File.createTempFile(context.cacheDir.toString(), fileName)'  this error occur "Caused by java.io.IOException Unable to create temporary file"

Comment: As i see you're creating duplicate of file and retrieve duplicate file path, it's not a solution.

Answer (score 21):

//The following code is working in Android N:

```
private static String getFilePathForN(Uri uri, Context context) {
    Uri returnUri = uri;
    Cursor returnCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(returnUri, null, null, null, null);
    /*
     * Get the column indexes of the data in the Cursor,
     *     * move to the first row in the Cursor, get the data,
     *     * and display it.
     * */
    int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
    returnCursor.moveToFirst();
    String name = (returnCursor.getString(nameIndex));
    String size = (Long.toString(returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex)));
    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), name);
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        int read = 0;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        int bytesAvailable = inputStream.available();

        //int bufferSize = 1024;
        int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);

        final byte[] buffers = new byte[bufferSize];
        while ((read = inputStream.read(buffers)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffers, 0, read);
        }
        Log.e("File Size", "Size " + file.length());
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
        Log.e("File Path", "Path " + file.getPath());
        Log.e("File Size", "Size " + file.length());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
    }
    return file.getPath();
}
```

Comment: You should add an explanation for what your code is doing and why this works and the code in question does not.

Comment: IllegalArgumentException: column '_data' does not exist this issue is occur in Android Naugat above method issue resolved.

Comment: The only soultion that worked perfectly. was struggling since 10 hours

Comment: It takes a lot of time if the file size is high.

Answer (score 3):

@Redturbo
I can't write a comment, I write here

```
IOUtils.copyStream(inputStream, outputStream);
```

TEMP_DIR_PATH - any your directory path, something like this

```
 File rootDataDir = context.getFilesDir();
 File copyFile = new File( rootDataDir + File.separator + fileName + ".jpg");
```

Comment: What would you have written if you could write the comment?

Answer (score 0):

Further adding to Vidha's answer as per Android R storage framework guide and if you do not want to permanently save the copied file to storage:

```
    public static String getFilePathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    File folder;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        folder = new File (Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)+ "/"+ "yourAppFolderName" );
    } else {
        folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"+ "yourAppFolderName");
    }
    // if you want to save the copied image temporarily for further process use .TEMP folder otherwise use your app folder where you want to save
    String TEMP_DIR_PATH = folder.getAbsolutePath() + "/.TEMP_CAMERA.xxx";
    //copy file and send new file path
    String fileName = getFilename();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(fileName)) {
        File dir = new File(TEMP_DIR_PATH);
        dir.mkdirs();
        File copyFile = new File(dir, fileName);
        copy(context, contentUri, copyFile);
        return copyFile.getAbsolutePath();
    }
    return null;
}

public static void copy(Context context, Uri srcUri, File dstFile) {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(srcUri);
        if (inputStream == null) return;
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(dstFile);
        IOUtils.copyStream(inputStream, outputStream);
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String getFilename() {
    // if file is not to be saved, this format can be used otherwise current fileName from Vidha's answer can be used
    String ts = (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US)).format(new Date());
    return ".TEMP_" + ts + ".xxx";
}
```