# How can I get File from URI in Android?

Tags: java, android, file, pdf, uri

I am trying to read a PDF file but it's throwing a `NoSuchFileException`. I have seen some solution for this but nothing seems to work in my case. I want to read the PDF file. Below is my code:

```
 private void requestForResume() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Upload PDF File");
    startActivityForResult(chooser, REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Here is how I am converting to file:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        String fileName = uri.getLastPathSegment();

        File resumeFile=new File(uri.getPath());
        try {

            PDDocument pdfResume=PDDocument.load(resumeFile);
            PDFTextStripper stripper=new PDFTextStripper();
            String resumeText=stripper.getText(pdfResume);
            Log.d("location",resumeText);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("location","unable to load pdf"+e.toString());
        }

        fileEditText.setText(fileName);        
    }
}
```

Please help me where I am wrong.

Comment: try File file= new File(Uri.toString());
file.getAbsolutePath();

Comment: I tried Uri.toString its not working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42508921/2252830

Comment: @pskink it is not working

Comment: what is not working? `openInputStream` is not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert file: Uri to File in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975197/convert-file-uri-to-file-in-android)

Comment: I want file Path not stream

Comment: whats wrong with the `InputStream`? what do you need file path for?

Comment: i was using PdfBox to read content of pdf and generate some information from it . But now i realize that it uses some swing and awt feature and it will not work in android.

Answer (score 1):

use this it return you path put just it on File

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static String getFilePath(Context context, Uri uri) throws URISyntaxException {
    String selection = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    // Uri is different in versions after KITKAT (Android 4.4), we need to
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(uri)) {//DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context.getApplicationContext(), uri))
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
        } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
        } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }
            selection = "_id=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{
                    split[1]
            };
        }
    }
    if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
        };
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver()
                    .query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

File file =new File(getFilePath(getApplicationContext(),data.getData()));

Comment: What about pdf file, means if i want storage path of pdf file or any other different document, it only runs for images/videos

Comment: You have used 3 methods {isExternalStorageDocument, isDownloadsDocument, isMediaDocument}. Where are their definitions??