# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Notes/fact50Result.txt: open failed ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android

I am trying to export the results of a factorial calculation in a txt file.
I found this code that looked quite straight forward from this article [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152125/how-to-create-text-file-and-insert-data-to-that-file-on-android)
However I'm getting the error on the title. What am I doing wrong?

I have typed this into the manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And this is my code related to saving:

```
    public void save(View v) {
     if(numOnRAM!=-1) {
         EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.resultTextBox);
         String data = text.getText().toString();
         generateNoteOnSD(this,"fact"+numOnRAM+"Results.txt", data);
     }
}

public void generateNoteOnSD(Context context, String sFileName, String sBody) {
    try {
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Notes");
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }
        File gpxfile = new File(root, sFileName);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
        writer.append(sBody);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        Toast.makeText(context, "File "+sFileName+" saving success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//After adding this 
//toast message did I realise the error thar occurs.

    }
}
```

Comment: Is the result of `root.mkdirs()` successful? And what API are you targeting?  If it's API 23 or above [you'll need to request permissions at runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: @MichaelDodd Im sorry but I've just started learning android. How to find out if `root.mkdirs()` is succesful? How to find out what API I am targeting after I created the project? Thank you.

Comment: [mkdirs()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()) returns a boolean, `true` if the directories were created, `false` if not. You can find your API target level in your app's `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @MichaelDodd Is it this one `targetSdkVersion 26`? I cant find any new directory.

Comment: Yes. That means you'll need to request permission to write to external stoage at runtime.

Comment: @MichaelDodd What would I have to do in order to achieve it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you need to [request permissions at runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) to allow your app to write to external storage. You can check if your app has the permission already by using [`checkSelfPermission()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)). For example:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // Do the file write
} else {
    // Request permission from the user
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, 
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
    ...
}
```

In order to handle this permission request, you'll also need to implement [`onRequestPermissionsResult()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)) from `OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback`, for example:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 0:
            // Re-attempt file write
    }
}
```

Read the documentation for full information.

Answer (score 5):

I think you have to request permission on runtime. Please check the code below:

```
 final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 123;

      private void requestPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
            ActivityCompat
                    .requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
        }
    }

        @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Permission Granted
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } else {
                    // Permission Denied
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same issue, you can remove the android:MaxSdkVersion attribute from the merged manifest as follows.

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />
```