# Get filename and path from URI from mediastore in Nought and Oreo device

Tags: android

I have image uri like this :"**content://com.iceburgapp.provider/external_files/.pkgName/File1.jpg**"

Now whenever I get path it give me : "**/external_files/.pkgName/File1.jpg**"

I want to get RealPathFrom content Uri.
I got solution from stackoverflow and I tried below code but not working for me :

```
    public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
  Cursor cursor = null;
  try { 
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
  } finally {
    if (cursor != null) {
      cursor.close();
    }
  }
}
```

AnyOne know How to do this? I got below error for using above code.
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_data' does not exist. Available columns: []**

It's only not working in the Nought and oreo device because of contentUri using file provider.

Comment: You may try with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42508921/6238866

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`. Ideally, just use that stream directly, for whatever it is that you are trying to do. Or, use that `InputStream` and some `FileOutputStream` on a file that you control to make a copy of the content, then use that file.

> **This is working properly in devices before Android N**